# Switch to another file page in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I'm making a simple application for school, but one thing just wont work. I'm trying to make a button, that when you press it, you go to another page, aka, loads a new fxml file.
here's my code for the buttons so far.

```
<Button prefWidth="240.0" styleClass="first, active" text="HOME">
    <VBox.margin>
        <Insets top="40.0" />
    </VBox.margin>
</Button>
<Button prefWidth="240.0" styleClass="first, active" text="Dashboard">
    <VBox.margin>
        <Insets top="40.0" />
    </VBox.margin>
</Button>
```

and I cant seem to make the button for Dashboard work so that it loads the Dashboard Page

Comment: Please post the event handler code where you have tried to implement loading the new UI.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if I totally understood your question but here's a possible solution : Follow the tutorial in this : [managing multiple screens in javafx](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1)

it's clear, easy and well organised and you can dowload the full implementation with three testing screens